# Can Jupyter notebook's bash_kernel be installed in a windows 7 OS

Tags: windows, awk, sed, cygwin, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook offers bash_kernel. Installation fails in a windows machine as 'pip' couldn't install [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) 3.3 which is a dependency for bash_kernel along with ipython3. Refer [link](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel) for steps to install Bash_kernel.

Jupyter Notebook's bash_kernel could serve as a Notebook style development env for Bash. There is a good old tradition of using Unix-like terminal in Windows machine to take advantage of excellent data processing packages like Grep, sed, awk. I do use Unix terminal emulator for windows like Cygwin. But I am in need for a Notebook style dev env for cygwin.

Is there any way I could run this bash_kernel in a Jupyter Notebook running on a windows7 machine? Or Is there any alternative Notebook style development environments for Cygwin or other Bash emulators running windows?

Comment: bash_kernel currently relies on Unix-only features (ptys), so it won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash_kernel requires Python3. On cygwin, python is version 2.x. You need to install and use python3.

The following worked on Cygwin64 bit:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
python3 -m pip install pexpect
python3 -m pip install bash_kernel
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just like to add one more information. For users having trouble with SSL certification error, download get-pip.py and add this line of code. 'python3 get-pip.py --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org', 'python3 -m pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org pexpect' and so on.
'

Comment: python get-pip.py --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org

this worked with Cygwin 2.7.10 on 64bit windows 7
this took too long to find....... lol, the url for pypi should be prefixed with http as it is a url