# Error running pip install in cygwin

Tags: python, ssl, cygwin, pymssql

I'm trying to install the python pymssql module in my cygwin environment with this command `$ pip install pymssql` and I'm getting this error:

```
Collecting pymssql
  Using cached pymssql-2.1.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools_git/: unknown error (_ssl.c:2738) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-git/: unknown error (_ssl.c:2738) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools_git' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown error (_ssl.c:2738) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or download links found for setuptools-git
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-epkoy3e7/pymssql/setup.py", line 464, in <module>
        ext_modules = ext_modules(),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 265, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 310, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 830, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1075, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1087, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 377, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools-git')
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'CYGWIN_NT-6.1'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('', '')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = []
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
```

I've updated pip to 8.1.1, updated openssl to 1.0.2g. I'm getting the same problem with any python module, not just pymssql.

Comment: See last comment on `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901613/can-jupyter-notebooks-bash-kernel-be-installed-in-a-windows-7-os`

Comment: I can't even download get-pip.py. I get these errors when I run wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py:ERROR: The certificate of ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’ is not trusted. ERROR: The certificate of ‘bootstrap.pypa.io’ hasn't got a known issuer.

Comment: it works fine for me. Are you sure you have the latest `ca-certificates` package ? Try downloading get-pip.py with a browser