# Cygwin python installing certificates

Tags: python, ssl, cygwin, pip

I am trying to run a script to install pip, and I get:

```
 $ python get-pip.py
 Collecting pip
   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2825) - skipping
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for pip
```

I have tried to download certs to pem file using openssl and append to the store:

```
 $ python -c "import requests; print requests.certs.where()"
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I tried to create my own key store and pass using an env variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE

I tried to start the scripe via os:

```
 python -c "import os;verify=False;os.system('./get-pip.py')"
```

Nothing. Works. It keeps complaining about SSL verification failing. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901613/can-jupyter-notebooks-bash-kernel-b%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be-installed-in-a-windows-7-os` and relative comment

Comment: @matzeri Thank you so very much, from the link this did the trick on Python 2.7.10 on 64bit cygwin:

python get-pip.py --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org

Comment: Put it as answer. It will help the next one with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install everything in cygwin using answers from the link posted by matzeri with minimal effort:

[Can Jupyter notebook's bash_kernel be installed in a windows 7 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901613/can-jupyter-notebooks-bash-kernel-b)‌​%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be-installed-in-a-windows-7-os

Also this was helpful, I didn't know where to find a lot of the libraries required, turned out they were in Cygwin already:

https://www.codefull.org/2015/12/installing-scipy-numpy-and-matplotlib-under-cygwin/

From the article: you need to have liblapack-devel and libopenblas installed via Cygwin’s package manager (SciPy depends on them). You also need to have gcc-fortran, python-gtk2, tcl-tk, ‘libpng’, pkg-config and a bunch of other stuff (that pip installer complains about) installed. The dependencies that pip complains about are straightforward (just mark them for installation in Cygwin’s installer).

To install scipy, numpy and matplotlib I had to call it like so:

```
 pip install -U scipy --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org
 pip install -U numpy --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org
 pip install -U matplotlib --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```